# Laravel Dompdf how to download two pdf files together

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, dompdf

As I click button I want to download the receipt and balance pdfs. Currently, in both pdf only one pdf receipt.pdf is generating (I need to generate both). My code :

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('receipt',$data);

$pdf2 = PDF::loadView('balance',$data);

return $pdf->download("receipt.pdf");// only receipt pdf generates

return $pdf2->download("balance.pdf");
```

Comment: You cannot download two files at a time. How about zipped it?

Comment: `Return` means the end of the function. No statement will be executed after the first `return`. Could your question be _How to return two values from a function?_

Answer (score 0):

You have to download them as a .zip file. Try this :

```
$file = file_get_contents('url_provided_by_the_user');
$destinationPath = public_path() . '/location/to/save/'.$filename . '.extension';
file_put_contents($destinationPath, $file);
}
```